# How can I add user `first_name` in this queryset? (this is incorrect)

Tags: django

```
class Mydata(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=199)
    about = models.TextField()
```

How can I add user `first_name` in this queryset? (this is incorrect)

```
mydata = Mydata.objects.filter(Q(company__contains=term) | Q(about__contains=term)| Q(user.first_name__contains))
```

Comment: Try `Q(user__first_name__contains)`.

Comment: Great, posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use double-underscore notation to follow `ForeignKey` relationship:

```
Q(user__first_name__contains)
```

Hope that helps.